# Run multiple jar files from batch file one by one

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I've exported my Java projects into a runnable jar file with the libaries combined in another folder. I'm trying to the first one to run, when it finishes the second one starts, etcetera. Right now this is what my batch file looks like:

```
java -jar "C:\path-to-project1.jar" parameter /wait
java -jar "C:\path-to-project2.jar" parameter /wait
java -jar "C:\path-to-project3.jar" parameter /wait
java -jar "C:\path-to-project4.jar" parameter /wait
java -jar "C:\path-to-project5.jar" parameter /wait
```

However I'm getting the noclassdeffounderror. The only class I'm using in the projects is the main class, which is called "Main.java". It also says " a jni error has occurred. please check your installation and try again".

Should I also call the .lib files or am I missing something else?

This is what the cmd prompts:

```html
 
C:\Users\EVE\Desktop>java -jar "C:\Users\EVE\Google Drive\Bots\LIVE BOTS\Builds\
Amsterdam-3-172-Heiniken music hall.jar" main parameter /wait
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/N
oSuchElementException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementEx
ception
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
 
C:\Users\EVE\Desktop>java -jar "C:\Users\EVE\Google Drive\Bots\LIVE BOTS\Builds\
Amsterdam-3-293-Roode Bioscoop.jar" main parameter /wait
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/N
oSuchElementException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementEx
ception
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
 
C:\Users\EVE\Desktop>java -jar "C:\Users\EVE\Google Drive\Bots\LIVE BOTS\Builds\
Amsterdam-4-223-Krakeling.jar" main parameter /wait
LOOP EC=2 EH=1 -----------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------
While 1 ------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Functions
        at Main.main(Main.java:250)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Functions
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace. It is not clear, if the main class is not found or a library class. But if you use libraries, you should include your JARs with the `-cp` command line switch.

Comment: Here is the `java` tool's reference documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: I posted the whole error log. I'll try and add the libraries with -cp. Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the classpath like 'SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;c:\ Selenium-xxxxxx.jar' - do this in the first lines of the batch file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whethere there are more bugs in the code but one is the location of `/wait`. Try `start /wait java -jar "C:\path-to-project1.jar" parameter` instead.